# How concatenate column varchar values in group by?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-phoenix

I want to do a select where for one column, I concatenate the values. For example, if I have the rows:

```
ID     NAME        Friend
1      Joe         Fred
2      Jeff        Fred
3      Joe         Jack
4      Joe         Sally
```

And I grouped by name, I would get:

```
Joe     Fred,Jack,Sally
Jeff    Fred
```

Is there a function to do this in Phoenix?

It would be something like:

```
SELECT
  NAME,
  CONCAT( Friend, "," )
FROM People
GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: I don't think Phoenix supports this functionality.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there a way to select that column and aggregate it into an array?

Comment: looks like you can make use of a user defined function then use NTH value function.  https://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#nth_value. IDK how to do it since I dont have phoenix installed.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I'm sorry, I don't understand. How would nth value help?

Comment: it is one of the window functions in phoenix that i see. when you do nth_value(column, n) you are getting the nth row of group by a given column. thus for 1 to n, you will get the array like the result of group_concat in mysql.